# What are the golden keys for in Chicken Invaders 4?

Tags: chicken-invaders-4

In *Chicken Invaders 4: Ultimate Omelette*, one type of powerup is a key with glowing golden aura.  What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've eventually found the answer myself on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_Invaders#Chicken_Invaders_4:_Ultimate_Omelette)

> "...The weapons from Revenge of the
> Yolk are available as "unlockables".
> Ultimate Omelette unlockables can be
> purchased individually by collecting
> keys, which are dropped from destroyed
> enemies during the course of the
> game...."

To expand on that, it seems that those unlockables are graphical upgrades.
To get to the unlockables screen, you needs to click the "my career" button before starting a game and from there on the unlockables button.